# Why is vlookup returnig N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a excel file which has 4 columns on Sheet1 and I need to check If Email from Sheet 1, matches Email from Sheet2, then write the Date (B) column from sheet2 in sheet1

Tried something like that but it is returning N/A everytime

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!$B:$E,2,FALSE)
```

`Sheet1`
`First Name (A)| Last Name (B)| Email (C)| Phone (D)`

`Sheet2`
`First Name (A)| Date (B)| Last Name (C) | Phone (D)| Email (E)`

Comment: Use `XLOOKUP` if your version supports it, or else `INDEX`/`MATCH`.

Comment: If you wonder why `VLOOKUP` doesn't work, it is because in `Sheet2` the return column `B` is to the left of the lookup column `E`. Here are the basics: 1.) If you have `XLOOKUP`, use `=XLOOKUP(C2,Sheet2!E:E,Sheet2!B:B)`. 2.) If not, use `=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(C2,Sheet2!E:E,0))`. Search For `INDEX/MATCH`, `Lookup`, and similar in the Search box above or google it for more information.

Comment: xlookup worked perfectly.